# I keep getting a read issue [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Tags: python, windows

I have tried putting the `(r"F:\Server\ ... "r")` it says:

```
file.write(float(u) + '\n')
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'.
```

When I don't put the `r` were it is it will double \\ on me saying:

```
read issue [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'F:\\Server\\Frames\\Server_Stats_GUI\x08yteS-F_FS_Input.toff'.
```

Here is my code

```
import time

while True:
    try:
        file = open("F:\Server\Frames\Server_Stats_GUI\byteS-F_FS_Input.toff","r")
        f = int(file.readline())
        s = int(file.readline())
        file.close()
    except Exception as e:
        # file is been written to, not enough data, whatever: ignore (but print a message)
        print("read issue "+str(e))
    else:
        u = s - f
        file = open("F:\Server\Frames\Server_Stats_GUI\bytesS-F_FS_Output","w")    # update the file with the new result
        file.write(float(u) + '\n')
        file.close()
    time.sleep(4)  # wait 4 seconds
```

Comment: As it says: you are trying to add float and string. Convert your float to a string: `str(float(u))`

Comment: so change the file.write(float(u)  to file.writestr(floau(u))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two separate errors here.

#### 1: Filename with Escape Characters

This error:

> read issue [Errno 22] Invalid argument:
> 'F:\Server\Frames\Server_Stats_GUI\x08yteS-F_FS_Input.toff'.

...is in the `open()` function.

Your filename has an escape character in it. '\b' is being evaluated to '\x08' (backspace). The file is not found, which throws an error.

a) To ignore escape characters, you can either double the backslash:

```
"F:\Server\Frames\Server_Stats_GUI\\byteS-F_FS_Input.toff"
```

or b) use `r` (rawstring) as a prefix to the string:

```
r"F:\Server\Frames\Server_Stats_GUI\byteS-F_FS_Input.toff"
```

You've used the second way, which fixed that issue.

#### 2: TypeError on `write()`

The next error:

> file.write(float(u) + '\n') TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for
> +: 'float' and 'str'.

is in the `write()` function.

You're treating a float as a string. You need to a) convert it to a string before trying to append the newline:

```
file.write(str(float(u)) + '\n')
```

or b) use string formatting:

```
file.write("%f\n" % (float(u)))
```

Comment: Thanks works great the out put is 119649099776.000000 just need to find a way to get ride of the .000000

Comment: See the string formatting documentation here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language . You can specify the precision, e.g. : "%.0f\n" % (float(3))